# Solana rpc subscribe to account transactions

Tags: java, solana

I am trying to listen for transactions for an account, I need to know when a transaction is received and get the hash of that transaction.

I am using Solana's json rpc api on https://api.testnet.solana.com

What I tried so far:

[blockSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#blocksubscribe---unstable-disabled-by-default): is unstable and disabled by default.

[accountSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#accountsubscribe): this will send the account balance but not the transaction.

[logsSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#logssubscribe): tried passing account address as mentions but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2) then use [getConfirmedTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getConfirmedTransaction) to get the actual transaction.

Comment: the problem is that I am using java with the rpc api, I cant use web3.js

Comment: web3.js is just a really basic wrapper around the rpc api, and every feature can be implemented in another language quite easily if you follow the spec: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getconfirmedsignaturesforaddress2